# Bundling a library with C++ exe

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, winsock

I've been working on a project which uses the socket library for windows called winsock. Currently the only way I can develop or run this code is if I do it in Visual Studio with the C++ extension installed. The compiled exe also, only works on computers with Visual Studio C++ installed.

```
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
```

The above line is used in Visual Studio to link the code and the winsock library.

My problem is this. I want to be able to "bundle" all of these together so I can give this project to someone without Visual Studio. I've searched online a bit, but not sure what's relevant to my case here.

Can anyone guide me on the procedure?

Comment: You need to [make an installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/windows-installer-portal) to package it up like that if you're talking about distribution, especially to machines that may not have that library. If you're talking about someone else with Visual Studio then they already have that file.

Comment: Take for example the `ws2_32.lib` library, it's not a full library but rather a companion library for the system DLL `ws2_32.dll`, which every Windows system should already have. And the `.lib` files are only used when linking our application, those are never needed for run-time.

Comment: The concept you are looking for is *static linking*. Unfortunately Microsoft do not make this possible with the winsock library.

Comment: @john Doesn't have to be static linked, though that is one way to bundle it. You can just install it as part of the package. Unfortunately this is why most Windows machines have a gazillion copies of things like the DirectX Runtime.

Comment: @tadman It would be better for the installer to find the winsock library the customer already has, rather than include your winsock library in the installer package.

Comment: I use Winsock and I don't have to bundle anything - it's part of the OS.

Comment: So what's the conclusion exactly? Do all windows installations possess this library? Is so, how do I find it. Because I tried it, and it through 2 missing dll erorrs. Otherwise is an installer the only option?

Comment: Are you using a debug build? You can't run a debug build on just any computer because you need special debug variants of system libraries.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. I'm just running the regular version, the way I've been doing all my programs uptil now. But I do click on "Debug" to actually run the program.

Comment: Perhaps your question should be "I have these two missing DLL's, X.dll and Y.dll, what do I have to do to find them or install them with my program?" Specifically, ***what are the missing DLL's?***

Comment: Most people will like an installer anyway, so they have a start menu entry ans stuff like that. IMHO, every developer should know how to build an installer. I like [innosetup], because it's text based and nicely diffs in the repository.

Comment: @StormClaw: The last time Windows didn't include the WinSock library with it was Windows 3.x back in the early 1990s.  By "Windows For Workgroups 3.11" I think it started being included.  Windows 95/98/Me definitely have it, as do all versions of Windows NT (which replaced the consumer Windows product as of Windows XP)

Comment: Now, somewhere in there was probably a version that came with WinSock 1.0 and you'd have to install WinSock 2.0 with your app, but that still would be ancient history.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost certainly the C and C++ Language Runtime Library aka "CRT", and not winsock, that is missing.  You overlooked the CRT because you didn't have to do anything to link with it, the linker includes it by default (unless you pass `/NODEFAULTLIB`).

Visual Studio *does* allow you to statically link the CRT.  In your project properties, under C/C++ -> Code Generation, change "Runtime Library" to `/MT` (Multi-threaded, NOT Debug, NOT DLL).

[image]

Comment: A quick search on static search shows that it bundles the library into the executable. So if you're correct about the required library being the CRT, and I statically link it to my executable like you described, I'll be able to distribute it?

Comment: @StormClaw: The license does allow you to redistribute the release version of the library, including by linking it in.  And does not allow you to redistribute the debug version of the library.